# Zen grids produces too large elements

Tags: drupal, grid, zen

I'm having problem with integration of zen-grids into drupal. I have installed sass and compass and using them. Then I created a content type with 3 fields. That give me structure in html like that:

```
<article class="node-1 node node-layout1 node-promoted view-mode-full clearfix" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" about="/node/1">

   <div class="field field-name-field-topleft field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field field-name-field-topmid field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field field-name-field-topright field-type-text-long field-label-above">
</article>
```

Then I tryied to use zen grids to create layout like that:

```
topleft___________topmid_______________topright
```

So I used that code:

```
$zen-column-count: 5; // Set the total number of columns in the grid.
.node-layout1{
   max-width:1200px;
  @include zen-grid-container; // Apply this mixin to the container.
}
.field-name-field-topleft {
  @include zen-grid-item(2, 1);
}
.field-name-field-topmid {
  @include zen-grid-item(1, 2);
}
.field-name-field-topright {
  @include zen-grid-item(2, 3);
}
```

All works kinda ok I get all 3 elements in line but their widths and offsets are way too large, topmid starts where topright should finish, so my page is way too large after that.

Here is css i get generated from compass for all 3 elements:

```
.field-name-field-topleft {
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: -200%;
width: 200%;
}
.field-name-field-topmid {
float: left;
margin-left: 100%;
margin-right: -200%;
width: 100%;
}
.field-name-field-topright {
float: left;
margin-left: 200%;
margin-right: -400%;
width: 200%;
}
```

I found out that the problem is in

```
$zen-column-count: 5;
```

not getting applied, it was set at start to 1 and seems that I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with compass 1.0, as documented here:

https://github.com/JohnAlbin/zen-grids/issues/68

A fix is to add $zen-float-direction, $zen-column-count to your zen-grid-item call, i.e.

```
@include zen-grid-item(2, 1, $zen-float-direction, $zen-column-count);
```

Answer (score 1):

use **!global** at the end of "$zen-column-count: 5" fixed it for me. it seems you must force zen to use new variable.

```
$zen-column-count: 5 !global;
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2346291#comment-9475791